# Is this an official source of the IOTA wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, iota-network, hardware-wallet

> https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases/tag/v2.5.7

Is this release from iota 
I have got v2.5.6 before I download just wanted to make sure this is right wallet and it’s not a scam 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your link is an official one and not scam.

Generally, all projects under https://github.com/iotaledger/* are maintained by the IOTA foundation (i.e. you can safely download from there).